# Customize BottomNavigationView to show text for the selected item, and icon for non-selected items

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to make this **`NavigationBottomView`**:

[image: (screen shot attached)]

All I want is to make selected item text instead of icon.

I googled it and tried to make custom `navigationBottomView` item, but I found nothing like what I want.

Comment: I think this is an icon not a text

Comment: @Zain is it possible to  be a text ?
or even can i hide the icon and dislpay item title only ??

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to be a text ? or even can i hide the icon and display item title only ?

Yes it's.

To control toggling `BottomNavigationView` item text, use  `app:itemTextColor` with a custom selector

- In your case you need to show up the text when an item is checked, and hide it otherwise.

To control toggling the item icon, use  `app:itemIconTint` with a custom selector

- In your case you need to show up the icon when an item is unchecked, and hide it otherwise.

For both text/icon cases you can use a transparent color as a hack for the hidden state.

Example:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    ...
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/text_selector"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/icon_selector"
```

text_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#FFEB3B" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

icon_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#FFEB3B" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

> i tried it before but all i got icon get hidden and text still at the
> bottom not shifted to the center like gif u sent

You can have the same behavior by changing the `BottomNavView` text size:

Create the following style to increase the item text:

```
<style name="BottomNavigationViewActiveItemText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Apply it to the `BottomNavigationView` with `app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationViewActiveItemText"`

If your item text can be in two lines, use also:

```
<style name="BottomNavigationStyle">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:lines">2</item>
</style>
```

And apply it with `android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationStyle"`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,
i tried it before but all i got icon get hidden and text still at the bottom not shifted to the center like gif u sent @Zain

Comment: @SeifE.Attia Welcome. Pls check UPDATE section in the answer

Comment: thank you so much for your efforts but text didn't move from its position :D

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that can you share your demo project or update your question with the layout